# How to retain the select state after submitting a query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I built a simple searchbox that has a select input box with multiple option to select from. I have the following Jquery Multiselect script running and working:

http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

But the only problem I have is that after selecting an option and hit submit, the options that were selected are cleared. What I need is for the selected options to remain selected when the page is refreshed.

Ive been trying to find similar questions but can't seem to get a clear solution. Here is my Jquery script. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("select").multiselect({
        selectedList: 4
    }).multiselectfilter();

});
</script>
```

UPDATE HTML select code:

```
                <select height="100" name="selSea" id="selSeaShells" size="5" multiple="multiple" onchange="loopSelected()">
                        <option value="">Search all clients</option>
                    <optgroup label="IMC COE1">
                        <option value="ACXSYS">ACXSYS</option>
                        <option value="ALC">ALC</option>
                        <option value="CDPQ">CDPQ</option>
                        <option value="CIBC">CIBC-CMO</option>
                        <option value="Interac">Interac</option>
                        <option value="Trade360">Trade360</option>
                    <optgroup label="IMC COE2">
                        <option value="B&I">B+I</option>
                        <option value="CGI Calgary">CGI-Calgary</option>
                        <option value="CIBC-PM">CIBC-PM</option>
                        <option value="CIU">CIU</option>
                        <option value="CPA">CPA</option>
                        <option value="CPC">CPC</option>
                        <option value="Davis & Henderson">D+H (Resolve)</option>        
                        <option value="DFAIT">DFAIT</option>
                        <option value="DOJ">DOJ</option>
                        <option value="Emera">Emera</option>
                        <option value="Energy Solutions">Energy Solutions</option>
                        <option value="FinanciaLinx">FinanciaLinx</option>
                        <option value="Greystone">Greystone</option>    
                        <option value="IIS-ICS">IIS-ICS</option>
                        <option value="Innovapost">Innovapost</option>
                        <option value="Northern Trust">Northern Trust</option>
                        <option value="OLG">OLG</option>        
                        <option value="Purolator">Purolator</option>
                        <option value="SCU-CUSS">SCU-CUSS</option>  
                        <option value="Wealth360">Wealth360</option>                
                        <option value="WSCC">WSCC</option>      
                        <option value="WSIB">WSIB</option>
                 </select>
```

Updated February 4th PHP code:

```
    <?php
        echo $hm->Button( array( 
            '<>'=>'<image/>',
            'name'=>"_sc=_this/search_pxy&_ssc=edit_init&{$param}&",
            'src'=>'icon_edit.gif',
            'value'=>RSTR_EDIT,
            'class'=>'btn_icon_edit'
        ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Store them in a cookie or localStorage onsubmit and then load them in on page load.

Comment: Since you're posting the data to the server, simply return the data from the server and select your multiselect.

Comment: You will need some type of persistence. Look into html5's localstorage or send metadata about the form off with the request and do something with it on the server end (database store/return with the response)

Comment: Yeah I came accross similar answers but can't figure how to get this working with my script, still very new with coding. Would anyone have an example I could look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an updated answer with localStorage. I have created a personal site for your reference here: http://localstorage.nfshost.com/

Now I will dump the code and explain each piece:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.multiselect.min.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.multiselect.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function supports_html5_storage() {
  try {
    return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
function isInArray(value, array) {
  return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#thelocalvalue').multiselect({
    header: "choose an option!"
  });
  if (supports_html5_storage()) {
   if (typeof localStorage['checked'] != 'undefined') {
  if (localStorage['checked'].length > 0 && localStorage['checked'] != null) {
    $('#thelocalvalue').multiselect('widget').find(':checkbox').each(function() {
      console.log(localStorage['checked']);
      if (isInArray($(this).val(),localStorage['checked'])) {
        this.click();
      }
      //console.log($(this).val());
     });
  } 
}
  $('#localhero').submit(function(e

) {
       e.preventDefault();
       localStorage['checked'] = $('#thelocalvalue').val();
       this.submit();
  });
  }
else {
  console.log('localstorage not supported');
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="localhero">
  <select id="thelocalvalue" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="1"> electron </option>
   <option value="2"> Delinger </option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Lets start with the first function at the top: supports_html5_storage - this function simply checks if the person's browser is localStorage compatible. If it isn't then it doesn't do anything.
The second function isInArray I pulled from stackoverflow. It pretty much checks if a value is an a JS array.

I then get multiselect working. I check to see if the browser supports localStorage and after that if the localStorage variable I set "checked" is empty or not. If it is empty then I simply move on. If not what I do is use multiselect methods to get the input of each, if the input's value is in the localStorage variable "checked" (which is an array) then I manually click the checkbox for the user (which the author of multiselect suggests).

On form submission I stop it, set the localStorage variable to contain all the select inputs' values in an array, then allow form submission. Feel free to ask me any questions. It is now working.

Comment: Yeha this might be a bit too advanced for me, im a bit confused on how to implement it into my code. I updated the main question with my select code. Not quite sure how I should put this in.

Comment: Ah yeah, you can only implement this into your code if you are going to save the data into a database, I could cook up an option with localstorage and JS, I just wanted to know more about what you are planning on doing with the selected values. Is the search itself working?

Comment: I have setup this tool http://www.phpkobo.com/address_book.php and its basically customizable address book. I have a search page that will let me search for contacts in my MYSQL database and it lets me input data into my database. Everything is working fine but its just that when I search something with the Jquery multiselect it clears my selection upon refreshing with the results. Ive tried looking into implementing a localstorage solution but can't seem to find a simple example to replicated to my site.

Comment: I have updated the answer to use JS localStorage with a working example you can reference. I even included multiselect specifics. If you have any questions let me know.

Comment: It worked! Your are the man Royalty and I really appreciate the detailed response as well.

Comment: Hi Royalty, i ran into a strange issue following the implementation of the script. My site also has the functionality to edit items and upon trying to edit an entry, you see the window to edit your entry but then quickly reverts back to the home page. I would message you privately but this site dosent seem to have that option. I would appreciate your help on this.

Comment: This seems like a separate issue. What are you using to edit an entry? Are you using this? https://github.com/victorjonsson/jquery-editable

Comment: Im using this tool: http://www.phpkobo.com/address_book.php. Looking at its code is uses a complex php mechanism. I updated my original post to add the part i believe would be useful.